# How to find the offset of the mov function in assembly?

Tags: assembly, cheat-engine

I don't know how to find the original memory address altered by this code.

```
mov [esi+10],eax
movzx eax,byte ptr [ebp+18]
```

The new address obtained is the `20847BB0`.

`eax: 003F6C39`
`esi: 20847BA0`
`ebp: 010FF1B8`

What is the previous address? Please with explanation.

Comment: The only store is to the 4 bytes at `esi+10`, and you have the ESI value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mov [esi+10],eax`

let's look at

`esi+10`

We know esi is 20847BA0, if you add 0x10 to it, you get 20847BB0 which is your "new address"

`movzx eax,byte ptr [ebp+18]`

ebp and esp define your local stack.  ebp+18 is a local stack variable

There is no other information provided, so that's all I can tell you